# I need to find the geohashes within a 10km radius of tdr706. How can I do it?

Tags: geohashing

I need to find all the geohashes that lie within a 10 km radius of the the geohash **tdr706** . How do i do it?

Comment: Do you still need it ? In case if you do, calculate the adjacent of the geohash. You can calculate the adjacents of adjacent till the distance is less than 10km. Each cell has a defined size so it should be doable.